# compressed image looks hazy android

Tags: android, image-compression

I am using [Whatsapp like image compression code](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/) for compressing the image taken from my custom camera.

The image after compressed looks hazy (little faded out) , looks like it has loosen its quality along with the size

Compress.java

```
public Bitmap compressImage(String imageUri) {

                String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

                int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
                int actualWidth = options.outWidth;

//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

                float maxHeight = 816.0f;
                float maxWidth = 612.0f;
                float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
                float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

                if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
                        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
                        } else {
                                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

                        }
                }

//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image

                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                options.inInputShareable = true;
                options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

                try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();

                }
                try {
                        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
                float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
                float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
                float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

                Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
                scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
                canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
                ExifInterface exif;
                try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
                        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                        if (orientation == 6) {
                                matrix.postRotate(90);
                                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                        } else if (orientation == 3) {
                                matrix.postRotate(180);
                                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                        } else if (orientation == 8) {
                                matrix.postRotate(270);
                                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
                        }
                        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                                true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                FileOutputStream out = null;
                String filename = getFilename();
                try {
                        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
                        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return getCompressesBitmap(filename);
        }

        public String getFilename() {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyFolder/Images");
                if (!file.exists()) {
                        file.mkdirs();
                }
                String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                return uriSting;

        }

        private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
                Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
                Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor == null) {
                        return contentUri.getPath();
                } else {
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                        return cursor.getString(index);
                }
        }

        public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
                final int height = options.outHeight;
                final int width = options.outWidth;
                int inSampleSize = 1;

                if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
                        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
                        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
                        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
                }
                final float totalPixels = width * height;
                final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
                while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                        inSampleSize++;
                }

                return inSampleSize;
        }

        public Bitmap getCompressesBitmap(String path) {
                Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                int nh = (int) (bitmapImage.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmapImage.getWidth()));
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapImage, 512, nh, true);
                return scaled;
        }
```

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your camera image is already compressed. So Set high quality image capture in your custom camera , because above compression code worked fine ,I have tested it.

Comment: no . my camera image size is more than 3 mb . means its not compressed

Comment: posted please have a look :)

Comment: Remove the function getCompressesBitmap because it downgrade your image scale . And return simply filename instead of getCompressesBitmap(filename)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can change in above solution is the hardcoded values for width and height of scaled down image. Try to write a function to store the phone's width and height in pixels whenever the app starts in your app's SharedPreferences. In the code where you set the width and height of scaled down bitmap, just use these values. It will ensure that the image is being displayed at best scale according to the device's hardware specifications without causing any Out of Memory exceptions and giving the best possible compression.

Comment: I changed scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out); this to scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); . any difference should it reflect?

Comment: compressing images in PNG format won't help because PNGs are lossless.

Comment: you will need to do bitmap compression in terms of size of screen and number of pixels available.